# What is the math term for a trilateral orthogonal pyramid with a right-angle triangle in the base?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, terminology, plane-geometry

I want to know the math term for **a trilateral orthogonal pyramid with a right-angle triangle in the base**, which is called "*bie nao*" in ancient china.

Comment: Interesting question! As far as I know this doesn't have a short English name.

Comment: For clarity, another way to describe this shape would the region bounded by four generic planes, where three of those planes pairwise meet at a right angle?

Comment: I kind of doubt there's a special word for this... Your description might be as close it can get to a "math term". For that matter, the Chinese term 鱉臑 is figurative and refers to the forelimb of softshell turtles. The analogous shape with a rectangular base, 陽馬, also has a figurative name meaning the corner of a hip roof. So I don't think there is necessarily a systematic way of naming it besides the descriptive and long-winded route.

Comment: FYI: The Mathematical Association of America's *Convergence* had an article ["Exploring Liu Hui’s Cube Puzzle" (maa.org)](https://maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/exploring-liu-hui-s-cube-puzzle-introduction) on a third-century dissection of the cube. As an historically-oriented piece, the article uses *bie'nao* (also, *quiandu* and *yangma*) as *the* name of the shape; while there's a description ("tetrahedron with four right-triangular faces"), there's no "also known as" name provided.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the figure is a kind of ["orthoscheme"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schläfli_orthoscheme), but that's a more-generic term.

Comment: @ElliotYu your comment seems like the most informed one.  Care to expand it to an answer?